# bash numbered functions

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a bash script with multiple functions.
The function are set out exactly as below:

```
func1()
{
command
}
func2()
{
command
}
```

My problem is thus: If I want to remove `func76()`. The sequence of numbered functions is broken. How do I change the numbered part of all the function names to put them back into sequence?
For instance, what was previously `func77()` will now become `func76()` and so on until the end.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The renaming task can quite easily be done with `awk`:

```
awk -v"a=1" '/func[0-9]+()/{$0="func"a"()";a+=1}1'
```

This replaces every line matching `func[0-9]+()` with a function name with an incrementing number and prints every line.

#### Explanations

- `-v"a=1"` – set `a=1` before execution of the program begins - `/pattern/{action}` – for lines matching the regular expression `pattern`, perform `action`
- `/func[0-9]+()/` – matches every line containing “func” followed by one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) and “()”
- `$0="func"a"()"` – set the currently processed line (`$0`) to “func” followed by the content of variable `a` and “()”
- `a+=1` – increase `a` by one
- `1` – shortcut to print the current line – in fact it‘s another statement with expression and action, just that the expression is simply `1` (= true for every line) and the action is the default one, which is `print`. You can replace this with `{print}` if you like.

#### Example run

```
$ <functions.bash cat
func1()
{
command1
}
func3()
{
command3
}
$ <functions.bash awk -v"a=1" '/func[0-9]+()/{$0="func"a"()";a+=1}1'
func1()
{
command1
}
func2()
{
command3
}
```